# How can i get selected date from ReactNative-DatePickerAndroid every time i pick it?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Is there some method, which handles changing of data every time, i pick new day, month or year? 
I use react-native-modal-datetime-picker.
Solution from here is not what i need [Get selected date from ReactNative-DatePickerAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703928/get-selected-date-from-reactnative-datepickerandroid).

Comment: I'm confius whether you're asking about ReactNative-DatePickerAndroid or react-native-modal-datetime-picker?

Answer (score 1):

From [ReactNative-DatePickerAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid.html) docs:

**static open[options]**

> Returns a Promise which will be invoked an object containing action,
>   year, month (0-11), day if the user picked a date

Since ReactNative-DatePickerAndroid return a promise after you select a date, you can use then. So,

```
DatePickerAndroid.open({...config})
          .then(function (date) {
            if (date.action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
              var newDate = new Date(date.year, date.month, date.day);
              console.log('selected date is: ', newDate)
            }
          });
```

Comment: this executes only when i open and close calendar.
Nut i need a moment, when i choose a date, but don`t close calendar.

Answer (score 1):

react-native-modal-datetime-picker works both for Android and iOS and get the selected date each time

DatePickerModal

onConfirm - once the date is selected from picker, fetching the selected date and modifications to it can be done in this.

To close the calender hide the picker in onCancel

Selected date can be formatted using moment

setFormattedDate(moment(sdate).format('yyyy-MM-DDT13:00:00.000Z'))

```
const showDatePicker = () => {
setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
hideDatePicker();

var currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
var currentDate = date.getDate();

if (currentMonth < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth; }
if (currentDate < 10) { currentDate = '0' + currentDate; }

let sdate = date.getFullYear()+"-" +currentMonth + "-" + currentDate ;
setDate(sdate)

  };


   <DateTimePickerModal
    style={{ width: 300, alignSelf: "center" }}
    isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
    mode="date"
    minimumDate={new Date()}
    onConfirm={handleConfirm}
    onCancel={hideDatePicker}
  />
```

For detailed description and complete code - https://github.com/ritzblogs/reactnative-datetimepicker